# Rails fails to return scripts/stylesheets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, public, gsub

This only happens on my local machine (Windows 7, Ruby 1.8.7). Occasionally rails will just stop returning my stylesheets/javascript and I'll get gross looking pages. If I navigate directly to those scripts, sometimes they work, and sometimes I get errors like:

```
private method `gsub!' called for #<Class:0x76ff830>
```

What could be causing this? It is usually more a nuisance than anything because of lack of styles, but when I'm trying to test out my javascript it becomes an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating my rails gem to 2.3.5 fixed this!